# How do I add a simple string on top of series of Radio Buttons?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am experimenting with GUI in Java and ran into a problem adding a single string on top of a series of Radio Buttons. Originally, I am trying to simulate a pizza order form. For example, I would like my the app to look like this:

size

.Large Pizza - 10$ 
.X-large Pizza - 15$ 
.Small - 7$

(Imagine that the bullet points are actual radio buttons)

This is what I have accomplished so far:

```
class  SizePanel extends JPanel{

    public SizePanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("Size");

        // Create Radio buttons
        JRadioButton large = new JRadioButton("Large - $11.99 + $1.50 / reg topping + $2.00 / prem topping", true);
        JRadioButton xlarge = new JRadioButton("X-Large - $13.99 + $1.50 / reg topping + $2.00 / prem topping");
        JRadioButton small = new JRadioButton("Small - $7.99 + $1.00 / reg topping + $1.50 / prem topping");

        // Group the radio buttons
        ButtonGroup sz = new ButtonGroup();
        sz.add(large);
        sz.add(xlarge);
        sz.add(small);
        add(label1);
        add(large);
        add(xlarge);
        add(small);
    }
}
```

However, When I run it the output is not what I expect. I get something like this:

[image]

How can I make it so the Radio Buttons are aligned and the word ("Size") is on top of the radio buttons?

Comment: Read up on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: also consider setting a `TitledBorder` instead of adding a `JLabel` - `setBorder(new TitledBorder("Size"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of row specified in `GridLayout` is too small. 3 rows for 4 components (in one column) does not make sense.
This causes the layout to be not as expected. Use

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
```

Or better, as Carlos Heuberger
[commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846994/how-do-i-add-a-simple-string-on-top-of-series-of-radio-buttons/52847303#comment92610498_52847303):

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1)); //one column any number of rows
```

Comment: or `setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));` meaning just one column (any number of rows)

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with aligment
xlarge.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
Or you can set absolute coordinates

setLayout(null);
xlarge.setLocation(20,20);